# Can we have multiple jms destinations connected to a same Spring cachingconnectingFactory

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I am consuming events from multiple Jms destinations. Can I use the same CachingConnectionFactory for subscribing events from all of the Jms destinations

Answer (score 0):

Yes; that's generally the approach - they all share the same connection but have different sessions.